# What would a life be like if humans had to keep moving around a constant path, at a constant rate around the planet?

Tags: humans, economy, culture, survival

I have an idea for my world, which involves a population of 200K to 500K people moving around the world all the time, in order to escape a climatic/geographical condition that chases them. There is a further complication in the form of destruction of all plants and animals by this climatic condition as it moves. So flora, fauna and humans are all on the move, constantly, to survive.

What would the major occupations be?

Comment: Check _Inverted World_ by Christopher Priest and _Dichronauts_ by Greg Egan, which have similar setups to what you describe, although in both cases the condition is more mathematical than geological.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Vivian*! Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Each of your questions is extremely broad and there are multiple questions. Please check out [How would people living in eternal day learn that stars exist?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/65323/how-would-people-living-in-eternal-day-learn-that-stars-exist) and other questions about 9-year-days from that author which might help you. And https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-i-have-a-high-concept-please-do-my-work-for-me-questions

Comment: Also *Absolution Gap* by Alistair Reynolds. And if memory servers, part of the Red/Green/Blue Mars series has something similar happening on Mercury.

Comment: @AndrewDodds You can use italics by surrounding text with asterisks ("\*"). For example *this text*.

Comment: @Secespitus - ta

Comment: Exactly, just this happens on Mercury in the Red/Green/Blue Mars series.

Comment: @Molot, this question does not ask about physiology. Why is it a duplicate?

Comment: The supposed "duplicate" has almost exactly the same setup, but does not answer **this** question at all. The supposed "duplicate" asks about physiology, not **occupations**, and has no answers dealing with **occupations** at all.

Comment: @Amadeus The author of this question was the one who marked this as a duplicate. Otherwise it wouldn't say *Community*. It looks like the author found his solution.

Comment: @Secespitus I did not realize that.

Answer (score 2):

I see this question as strongly related to [this one](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/85878/30492).

Having a population to be constantly on the move will prevent the onset of agriculture and, as a consequence, the development of cities as we know them since Babilonian age.

With a constantly moving population you can have hunters and gatherers, you can have livestocks, but you cannot afford the luxury of waiting one or more years to harverst your fields.

Therefore the most likely occupations you will end up having are:

- Hunters/warriors (most likely adult men)
- Harvesters (women)
- Sheperds (young men)